# how to get a list of tuples for my xml attributes

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I use python and ElementTree for parsing my xml files. Lets assume I have the following content:

```
<basic name="myAssignments" type="INTEL">
       <sirius dataType="UINT">
             <assignmnt>
                    <side_a value="a0" desc="sirius_desc_a0"/>
                    <side_b value="b0" desc="sirius_desc_b0"/>
             </assignmnt>
             <assignmnt>
                    <side_a value="a1" desc="sirius_desc_a1"/>
                    <side_b value="b1" desc="sirius_desc_b1"/>
             </assignmnt>
             <assignmnt>
                    <side_a value="a2" desc="sirius_desc_a2"/>
                    <side_b value="b2" desc="sirius_desc_b2"/>
             </assignmnt>
       </sirius>
</basic>
```

I am not getting it to return a list of all the assignments as a list with tuples in this format:

```
[(a0,"sirius_desc_a0",b0,"sirius_desc_b0")
(a1,"sirius_desc_a1",b1,"sirius_desc_b1")
(a2,"sirius_desc_a2",b2,"sirius_desc_b2")]
```

In this case the list will have a len of 3 and each object is a tuple with the mapping just in simple order.

Can someone give a help?

I got to know how I can fetch a single attribut of an element, but here I need multiple attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
from pprint import pprint

text = '''\
<basic name="myAssignments" type="INTEL">
       <sirius dataType="UINT">
             <assignmnt>
                    <side_a value="a0" desc="sirius_desc_a0"/>
                    <side_b value="b0" desc="sirius_desc_b0"/>
             </assignmnt>
             <assignmnt>
                    <side_a value="a1" desc="sirius_desc_a1"/>
                    <side_b value="b1" desc="sirius_desc_b1"/>
             </assignmnt>
             <assignmnt>
                    <side_a value="a2" desc="sirius_desc_a2"/>
                    <side_b value="b2" desc="sirius_desc_b2"/>
             </assignmnt>
       </sirius>
</basic>
'''

lst = []
tree = et.fromstring(text)
for a in tree.findall('*/assignmnt'):
    sublst = []
    for s in a:
        sublst.extend(s.attrib.values())
    lst.append(tuple(sublst))
pprint(lst)
```

Output:

```
[('a0', 'sirius_desc_a0', 'b0', 'sirius_desc_b0'),
 ('a1', 'sirius_desc_a1', 'b1', 'sirius_desc_b1'),
 ('a2', 'sirius_desc_a2', 'b2', 'sirius_desc_b2')]
```

If there are other nodes under `assignmnt`, you may want the more explicit:

```py
lst = []
tree = et.fromstring(text)
for a in tree.findall('*/assignmnt'):
    sublst = []
    for node in 'ab':
        sublst.extend(a.find(f'side_{node}').attrib.values())
    lst.append(tuple(sublst))
pprint(lst)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Thats works. One more thing: is there a way to add also the elements name (here it should be ''side_a" or 'side_b') in front of each tuple?

Comment: ok sure. I found it btw. It can be done with the ".tag" option. Thanks!